# MVVM - Does the View really need have to have a default constructor?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection

I'm just getting started with the MVVM pattern in WPF and I decided that the most elegant way to structure my code was injecting the view-model in to the view's constructor.

This is all well and good, but ReSharper gives a warning in the XAML that my view doesn't have a default constructor. I'm assuming that this is so that I can construct my view in XAML if required, but that's only a guess.

What am I giving up by requiring my view to take a view-model in the constructor?

**Edit:** My view constructor looks like this:

```
public ExampleView(ExampleViewModel viewModel)
{
    if (viewModel == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("viewModel");
    DataContext = viewModel;
}
```

**Answer:** I settled on the following set up, where the DesignTime namespace contains mocked up versions of the ViewModel for testing and design time support.

*ExampleView.xaml.cs*

```
public ExampleView()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

public ExampleView(IExampleViewModel viewModel)
    : this()
{
    DataContext = viewModel;
}
```

*ExampleView.xaml*

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="Wpf.Examples.ExampleView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:DesignTime="clr-namespace:Wpf.Examples.DesignTime">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <DesignTime:ExampleViewModel/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>

</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you correctly recognized, requiring a non-default constructor will deny you using that control from XAML. That also means no more design-support and your designers will probably hate you. Finally you break all sorts of nice data binding scenarios. Like using the control as an `ItemTemplate`.

As a remedy for the **missing design support**, I would suggest implementing a default constructor which creates a mocked view-model which doesn't need any infrastructure. That way you can support design mode very elegantly and putting the view in a XAML file (e.g. for testing) will do something sensible.

As a remedy for the **missing data binding support**, you should ponder whether it might be better to consume the view model via the `DataContext` of your WPF control. This is common in WPF and---as far as I can tell---the intended way to pass the model to the view in WPF.

Comment: I'm setting the DataContext in the constructor anyway, is there a better pattern for this?

Comment: Use a Factory? Set the DataContext manually? Create an empty default constructor?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you don't need designer support then I see no reasons.

Answer (score 0):

To keep designer support you need a default constructor. When you define your own constructor you basically loose the autogenerated default constructor. Just create an explicit default constructor and you should be fine.